# Counting the instances of a word in a column of first database table and add it to a row of another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two MySQL database tables: 'header' and 'lookup'.

I have a field called 'protocol' in my 'header' table in which the data will be filled if I run my packet capturing engine. And, I also have the 'info' field in which it will show me the type of message (for example, Type 135/ Type 137,etc.)
So, this field will contain the different types of protocols.

What I want to do is this:

1. I want to count the instances of a particular type of message in my first table (header). For example, I want to count the instances a particular protocol has type 135 (which will be shown in info).
   Will this be right? If not, please provide me the correct SQL.

   ```
   SELECT COUNT(info) FROM project.header WHERE info="Type 135";
   ```
2. The next thing I want to do is I want to insert the number of
   occurrences in the 'info' field in first table into 'count1' field
   of another table called 'lookup'.

   For example,
   If there are totally 5 instances of Type 135 messages in first table, I want to insert the number (5 here) into the corresponding field in the second table's field (count1) into the row which I created as "Type 135".

Please do provide me with the steps to achieve this.

Comment: You are close to the solution. The SQL that you have provided is seems to be correct. You can verify it manually on your database. You can write a Insert statement for the second one. Try reading online about insert statement in case if you don't know its syntax, its easy. If you are not able to get there, let us know where did you find difficulty. ::)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the row does not exist in `info`, then you use `insert`.  However, I am guessing the row does exist, so you use update with a correlated subquery:

```
update lookup l
    set count1 = (select count(*)
                  from project.header h
                  where h.info = l.info
                 );
```

You can add `where l.info = 'Type 135'` if you only want to update one row.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Gordon. Your solution worked like a charm!